# trace program network communications

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, network-adapter, tcpip

I'm looking for a program that can trace what a specific program on my computer is sending/receiving over my Ethernet connection. I'm not trying to crack a password or anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your update...

Wireshark wont let you filter by process, but depending on what kind of packets the process sends out, you  could get creative and filter by port or some other pattern in the packets (assuming any exists).
Otherwise, if youre running windows, netmon apparently lets you filter by process, but Ive never used netmon before and Im just repeating what Ive read somewhere else.

Comment: You are right, netmon does..  I think that's the best answer. I just tried it. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en     Here is a pic of the screen http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/5361/msnetmon.jpg   see left hand side of the window you can choose programs and it just displays the packets for that program.. netmon has nothing under filters for program, presumably because it's not data in a packet, but it still has the option to just show for each program or process rather.

Comment: Thanks barlop & alexl, filtering by port was a great idea and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The type of program you speak of is called a packet sniffer.  Wireshark(formerly known as Ethereal) is free and will do it.

Comment: Also, use netstat with the -o switch to display process ID. netstat can list connections and what process is making them. Ethereal can show you all that is in all the packets. You can use netstat or quicker, perhaps quicker, task manager or tasklist to see what process has what process id.

Comment: Yea I've used Ethereal, but it gives me the packets for all the connections over TCP, I just want to see packets for a single program. Unless there is a way with Ethereal that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Gootik I'm suggesting using netstat with -o to see what process uses what connection, then view the connection in detail with wireshark. There are some alternatives to netstat with -o.. A tiny free program called Active Ports is very good.. So Active Ports + Wireshark. Wireshark tells you everything. So you filter things in wireshark.  Of course Active Ports would tell you IP and Port, per program, that is what you need to know to know what to filter in Wireshark.

Comment: @Gootik yes the filtering by port in your case.. but I wouldn't use the word filtering for "filtering" by program. ethereal and netmon reserve the word for what is in the packet.